# equivalent to "Cloud Services" in new Azure portal?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, azure

I am really confused about how you can create the equivalent to "Cloud Services" in the new Azure Portal? In my understanding, Cloud Services is only a "Classic" feature now. In the new Azure Portal, I want to create a virtual network with a public IP address that has multiple VMs in it sharing that same Public IP. I want to control everything by port numbers. You know, just like a regular physical network. But now, they have VM level public IPs, each VM gets its own Public IP that you cant share. How can I create a virtual network with only one Public IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here. "Cloud Service" is basically the "old" way of doing this. The new way is described in detail in the following link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2016/02/04/azure-networking-public-ip-addresses-in-classic-vs-arm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for both web/worker cloud services, and virtual machine cloud services.

**Virtual Machines:**

Choose `+ New` then select compute and choose your VM type (e.g. Ubuntu):
[image: new vm]

Now be sure to change the dropdown to `Classic` and hit `Create`:

[image: create classic]

Now just fill in all the settings like you did in the old port, including the `cloudapp.net` name:

[image: parameters]

And you can choose an existing cloudapp if you want. There ya go...

**Web/Worker:**

In the new portal, just browse, and in the search box, start typing `Cloud Service`:

[image: Cloud Service browse]

Now you'll see your list of cloud services, and be able to add a new one:

[image: List classic cloud services]

Now just click `Add` to create a new one:

[image: Create new cloud service]

Just remember that you have to create your role definitions and related code within your dev environment. It's not like Virtual Machines where you can just spin up a new VM from a gallery (though you *can* upload and deploy from a deployment package:

[image: Upload deployment]